# r: use mapply function to two list

Tags: r, mapply

I have two lists [dd1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdyn0w72lux1ojn/d1.rda?dl=0) and [dd2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0run81mo9afsxv/d2.rda?dl=0). The sample data are:

dd1:

```
  > dd1
$`1`
  [1] 9.882462e-02 5.036365e-02 9.677686e-02 1.917278e-01 1.930706e-01 4.859976e-02
$`2`
  [1] 4.825651e-02 1.353690e-02 1.061587e-02 6.770033e-03 9.190913e-02 6.863396e-02
$`3`
  [1] 2.165620e-01 1.582611e-01 3.448556e-02 6.652456e-02 4.511841e-02 1.346382e-02
$`4`
  [1] 4.858856e-02 3.385838e-02 5.187566e-02 6.467315e-02 2.876072e-02 9.523681e-02
$`5`
  [1] 0.0418527703 0.0149859021 0.0059625537 0.0133805085 0.0670249342 0.0383909791
```

dd2:

```
> dd2
    $`1`
      [1] 1 0 0 1 1 0
    $`2`
      [1] 1 0 1 1 0 0
    $`3`
      [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0
    $`4`
      [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0
    $`5`
      [1] 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

I want to apply the `ROC` function to each of the five `vector` in the two `lists`, for example, i can use the `ROC` function to each `vector`, it works.

```
    library(pROC)
    roc1<-roc(as.factor(unlist(dd2$`1`)), dd1$`1`)
    roc2<-roc(as.factor(unlist(dd2$`2`)), dd1$`2`)
    roc3<-roc(as.factor(unlist(dd2$`3`)), dd1$`3`)
    roc4<-roc(as.factor(unlist(dd2$`4`)), dd1$`4`)
    roc5<-roc(as.factor(unlist(dd2$`5`)), dd1$`5`)
```

But I think it should be possible to use the function `mapply` to apply the `roc` function to each of the `vectors` of the two `lists`, and then return five `roc` result at a time. I suppose mapply function will apply the function to each vector in the list automatically. I wrote the `code` as

```
mapply(function(x,y) roc(as.factor(unlist(x)),y), dd2, dd1)
```

It doesn't work. Could any one tell me how to fix it?

(please click links dd1 and dd2 to get the data)

Comment: Please include sample data instead of pointing us to a dropbox site.  The links don't even work.

Comment: The data contain a lot elements. OK, I add sample data instead.

Comment: @lebelinoz Actually the link works, you can't preview, but you can download without logging in.

Comment: @lebelinoz I have add some data samples, could you have a check on the codes for me?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to give data examples.

Comment: @LeoP.  Instead of posting another quesion that how to use `dput()` to give data sample. If it is not a problem for you to change it as you like, maybe you can give me some instruction on how to use  `dput()` to change the data as you want.

Comment: Experts may feel annoyed that people do not ask a question with a responsible attitude, but I also wonder whether experts truly want to offer help.